# Error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." for CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, firebase-authentication

I get error for code work before in Xamarin Android using Visual Studio 16.2.5:

I try to search new requirements for my may be outdated code

In main Activity

```
FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Application.Context);
```

In function a call

```
var res = await FirebaseAuth.Instance.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password);
```

I get exception Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: So what's null?

Comment: email and password is have same data. You asking for something else?

Comment: Is FirebaseApp null? Is Application null? Is Application.Context null? Is FirebaseAuth null? Is FirebaseAuth.Instance null?

Comment: you are right - FirebaseAuth.Instance is null

Comment: Now i add work for me code
            var instance = FirebaseAuth.GetInstance(MainActivity.app);
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new FirebaseAuth(MainActivity.app);
            }
How it described in https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/223 but i not sure it is similar problem. I Have Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 71.1610.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do downgrade to version 60.1142.1 to fast fix problem